# Is my laptop with Optimus really using Nvidia GPU for WebgGL?

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, optimus

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Z500 with an Intel HD 4000 and an                                                                  NVIDIA GeForce GT 635M.
I have set in Nvidia Control Panel that Chrome uses Nvidia GPU, but when I go to `chrome://gpu` I see:

`GL_RENDERER    ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 Direct3D9Ex vs_3_0 ps_3_0)`

Moreover, if I go to http://alteredqualia.com/tmp/webgl-maxparams-test/
I see:

`Unmasked Renderer: ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 Direct3D9Ex vs_3_0 ps_3_0)`

But, if I run HWiNFO64 to check gpu activity and I launch one of the demanding WebGL demos cited at http://alteredqualia.com/texts/optimus/ I see that Nvidia GPU temperature, clock and Core Load increase as if Nvidia card is really being used.

So, which one is being used?

Comment: have you activated HW acceleration in advanced Chrome settings?

Comment: Of course, and I have also selected 'Override software rendering list' in chrome://flags